# Having issues with the Javascript Replace function

Tags: javascript

```
var my_string = "some text goes here!!!";
```

Why is it that `my_string.replace('!', '*', my_string);` only gives

```
some text goes here!!*
```

instead of `some text goes here***` ?

Any idea?

Comment: Add global fla **g**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default replace() only replaces the first occurrence.  To replace all occurrences, pass in the global flag, as in:

```
var my_string = str.replace(/!/g,"*");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can perform a global replacement by using g..

The g modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

```
var replaced_string=  my_string.replace(/!/g, '*');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the *global* flag `g`. This should suit your needs:

```js
.replace(/!/g, '*');
```